# Changing scores with If and Else

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a coin flipping game.

I have a math generator code which generates a number between 1 and 0.

If it's 1, do `score1` +1 point, otherwise `score2` +1 point.

However, it only works when number is 1. When it's 0, it doesn't change the second score's number.

```
else(random == 0) {
    document.getElementById("score2").innerHTML = score2++;
)
```

```js
var score1 = 1;
var score2 = 2;

function flipping() {
  var min = 0;
  var max = 1;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = random;
  document.getElementById("result").target = "random";

  if (random == 1) {
    document.getElementById("score1").innerHTML = score1++;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("score2").innerHTMl = score2++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="box2">
    <span id="score1"></span>
    <span id="score2"></span>
  </div>

  <div id="resmarg">
    Result: <span id="result"></span>
  </div>

  <button id="play" onclick="flipping()">Play</button>
</div>
```

When it's 1, the first score gets +1 point, when it's 0 the second one gets +1

Comment: this line is wrong: document.getElementById("score2").innerHTMl = score2++;
use innerHTML (HTML in all caps), not innerHTMl

Comment: Please read your code thoroughly and inspect the console errors before posting on SO. On your else statement you are calling `innerHTMl` (no capital L).

Comment: Why the CSS tag?

Answer (score 0):

There were some things to address to your existing code, here are the addressed points:

- Added the DOMContentLoaded event to actually render the initial score1 and score2 values (this is mandatory for the third point, otherwise you may not directly notice the issue).
- Fixed a typo, where `innerHTMl` was used instead of `innerHTML`.
- Changed `score1++` and `score2++` to, respectively, `++score1` and `++score2`. the reason for that is that, otherwise, you will print the **old value** of score1 and score2, due to the fact that `n++` increments the value and returns the **previous value**, while `++n` **increments and returns the updated value**.

Other than that, I'm not sure why the initial score values are 1 and 2, but still, this is the working code:

```js
var score1 = 1;
var score2 = 2;

function flipping() {
    var min = 0;
    var max = 1;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = random;
    document.getElementById("result").target = "random";
    if (random == 1){
        document.getElementById("score1").innerHTML = ++score1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("score2").innerHTML = ++score2;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
  document.getElementById("score1").innerHTML = score1;
  document.getElementById("score2").innerHTML = score2;
});
```

```html
<div class="game">
      <div class="box2">
          Score 1: 
          <span id="score1"></span><br />
          Score 2:
          <span id="score2"></span>
      </div>

      <div id="resmarg">
          Result: <span id="result"></span>
      </div>


      <button id="play" onclick="flipping()">Play</button>
  </div>
```